# How to modify the command to call Python

Tags: python, macos

On my Mac, `python` will run Python 2 and `python3` will run Python 3 in the terminal. How can I modify the command so I can call Python 3 with just `py`?

Comment: http://www.linfo.org/alias.html

Answer (score 2):

Add a new file in your home directory called `.profile`. In there, add a line:

```
alias py=python3
```

You'll have to start a new terminal session for this to have any effect.

Comment: you dont need to start a new terminal , you can source the `.profile` in the existing terminal using `. ~/.profile`

Comment: A rare +1 for a suggestion to use an alias :)

Answer (score 0):

Place you in the directory where the python3 executable is (with `cd` command).

Then, enter :

```
ln -s python3 py
```

This creates a symbolic link.

Comment: This requires write access to the directory where `python3` is located.